# Can't find error in code for finding path in the dictionary which demonstrates classes inheritance

Tags: class, recursion, inheritance

I'm trying to find path from one key in dictionary to another, demonstrating how classes inheritance works

I tried to run my code, using this input data, but it fails:
2
A : C B
B : D E
1
E A
I used print in find_path function to show that in the end it prints 'True', but the result is 'No'

```
classes={}
def create_path(classname1, parent_list):
    if classname1 not in classes.keys():
        classes.setdefault(classname1, {'parents': parent_list})
    else:
        classes[classname1]['parents']+=parent_list
    for i in range(len(classes[classname1]['parents'])):
        if classes[classname1]['parents'][i] not in classes.keys():
            create_path(classes[classname1]['parents'][i], [])
def find_path(a, b):
    print(a in classes[b]['parents'])
    if a in classes[b]['parents'] or a==b:
        return True
    else:
        for i in range(len(classes[b]['parents'])):
            find_path(a, classes[b]['parents'][i])
    return False
for i in range(int(input())):
    lst=input().replace(':', ' ').split()
    if len(lst)>1:
        create_path(lst[0], lst[1:])
    else:
        create_path(lst[0], [])
for j in range(int(input())):
    a, b=input().split()
    if find_path(a, b):
        print('Yes')
    else:
        print('No')
```